# PHP sort array by appearance

Tags: php

I have array that need to sort by their appearance, as they are written manually as my free will. Note the values are hints to be expected to appear:

```
  $options = array("the array retrieved from some forms");
  $items   = array();
  foreach ($options as $key => $val) {
    switch ($key) {
      case 'three':
        $items[]          = "this should come first";
        $items[]          = "now the second in order";
        $items[]          = "the third";
        $items[]          = "forth";

        switch ($val) {
          case 'a':
          case 'b':
            $items[]       = "fifth";
            $items[]       = "should be six in order";
            break;

          case 'c':
          default:
            $items[]    = "7 in order";
            break;
        }

        break;
```

...............

As you see the values can be anything, but what I need is to just implode and display the items based on their appearance. Its all manual order, what come first should be printed at top.

**Expected:**

```
"this should come first";
"now the second in order";
"the third";
"forth";
"fifth";
"should be six in order";
"7 in order";
```

**Current unexpected:**

```
"should be six in order";
"forth";
"7 in order";
"the third";
"fifth";
"this should come first";
"now the second in order";
```

But I can't seem to apply any of sorting from this http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php
I suspect those $items are ordered somewhere by the forms which I have no way to reorder. I just have power to write output and order as I want from top to bottom. But I can't inset keys into $items, simply because I need to reorder freely.

I took a look at the output, the keys are not sorted as expected.

Any hint is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When you use the `$var[] = ...;` syntax, PHP appends the value to the end of the array. Your array is out of order because the order of execution of your script is out of order.

Comment: Sounds explaining my problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way a php source appears to us is not same it is to compiler. So it's not possible that way. But it's possible (not in a good way) if you run a regex on the source.

Example:

```
$source = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
preg_match_all('#\$items\[\]\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"#', $source, $match);
// now $match[1] contains the strings.
$strings = $match[1];
```

Comment: Sound legitimate answer. Thanks

Comment: This is a terrible answer, the other posted answer is more correct.

Answer (score 2):

it seems the steps of fulfilling your array are not in order you want.

maybe you can use some trick to achieve what you want

for example insert "key pointer"

```
$ikey = 0;
$options = array("the array retrieved from some forms");
  $items   = array();
  foreach ($options as $key => $val) {
    switch ($key) {
      case 'three':
        $items[$ikey++]          = "this should come first";
        $items[$ikey++]          = "now the second in order";
        $items[$ikey++]          = "the third";
        $items[$ikey++]          = "forth";

        switch ($val) {
          case 'a':
          case 'b':
            $items[$ikey++]       = "fifth";
            $items[$ikey++]       = "should be six in order";
            break;

          case 'c':
          default:
            $items[$ikey++]    = "7 in order";
            break;
        }

        break;
```

i am not sure if this helps, because you posted uncomplete code.

> sorry for my english, if there are any mistakes